# Calling a 'Controller' method, when button clicked from 'View'

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have added a button as shown in the code below, I have added `id:'submitBtn'` so when this button is clicked the controller class `MyController` will get called and execute.

1.) How does the code know that it should go execute the Controller class ?

```
{
                   xtype:'button',
                   {
                   xtype:'button',
                   id:'submitBtn',
                   text:'Send',
                   ui:'confirm',
                   padding:5
                   text:'Send',
                   ui:'confirm',
                   padding:5
}
```

To check if everything is working i checked if the Controller class is getting called; Here's the code;

**MyController.js**

```
Ext.define('app.controller.MyController', {
           extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

       config: {
       refs : {
       submitBtn: '#submitBtn'
       },

       controls : {
       submitBtn: {
       onTap: 'submitData'
       }
       },
       },

       submitData: function() {
       var form = Ext.getCmp('form-id');
       alert("Came here!");

       var formvalues = form.getValues();

       // Web Service code goes here ..
       Ext.Ajax.request({
                        params: formvalues,                     
                        url:'http://mywebservice.com/web_ser'

                        success : function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success');
                        }

       }
       });
```

But, the alert was not displayed. I think the controller class was not called.

In the **app.js** class i have added the controller as shown below;

```
views: ['Main','Home', 'Contact'],
    controller:['MyController'],
```

Help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MyController.js`,

Change

1. `controls:`  to   `control:` and
2. `onTap :` to `tap :`

& it should work now.

> How does the code know that it should go execute the Controller class
>   ?

Check out the [documentation of controller](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers) for neat & complete explanation

Comment: also in the app.js `controller ` should be `controllers `